# How to farm non-respawnable bosses (Pre Respawnable bosses patch - Xbox 360)

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm trying to farm the Even-More-Disgusting Tork for a flakker but I've heard that he is non-respawnable. However, I've seen people get it anyway without the grinder. So how do people farm these non-respawnable bosses? I'm an Xbox-360 user. I've also heard about this dashboarding thing but I don't know how to use that either.

(I can't download the patch that make them respawnable)

Comment: You could copy your save file onto your desktop, kill the tork and if it doesn't drop the flakker just replace your original save file with the back up on your desktop.

Comment: Um I'm using my Xbox 360 does this work on it?

Comment: Didnt even see the 360 tag, if you want to go to the trouble it can. Also if it doesnt save as soon as you kill the tork you could just turn of your console without saving and you should be able to farm it like that.